# rabbit mq message listener

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, message-queue

Im using

```
@Autowired
RabbitTemplate temp;
temp.convertAndSend("aQueue", msg);
```

for sending and

```
@Autowired
RabbitTemplate temp;
return temp.receiveAndConvert("aQueue");
```

for receving  messages  from rappid mq 
Now I would like  to use  a listener  something like :

```
@Component

public class MessengerListener implements MessageListener{

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {


    }

}
```

The problem is that the on onMessage listener works with Messages  is it possible to receive simple  serializable objects in similar fasion ?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you do not do this, you should pass XML,JSON(i recommend json),etc. to onMessage(..) and unmarshal the responses, not serialized objects over JMS.

use something like below for unmarshalling/marshalling the payload

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency
```